# Android - How to display keyboard input in TextView as it is typed

Tags: java, android, user-interface, textview

In part of my android application I am trying to show the text I am typing as it is being typed WITHOUT a button/button listener. In other words I want to see the text in an EditText sent in real time to a TextView. Is this possible?

Comment: have you tried looking at the [Android Developer documents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)?

Answer (score 2):

//To open keyboard forcefully, mention the code into any listener or oncreate

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```

//To Trace Pressed Key

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:
        {
            textview.setText("A");
            //your Action code
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by calling addTextChangedListener on the EditText, and creating a new TextWatcher.

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
editText..addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
          changeTextView();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an EditText TextChangedListener.

```
textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        textView.setText(editText.getText().toString());
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```